# SpringBatch CommandLineJobRunner -next using old run.id

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

We are using the CommandLineJobRunner to execute Spring Batch jobs.  We are using -next on the command line:

```
java -Dlog4j.configuration=file:./prop/log4j.properties -Dlogfile=logfile_load_data -jar EtlLoadData.jar loaddata_etl_config.xml loaddata_etl_job -next
```

We started coming down with an error:

```
Job Terminated in error: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={run.id=10}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters. 

org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={run.id=10}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at  org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:122)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:168)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
at $Proxy14.createJobExecution(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:111)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349)
at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574)
```

I thought that if you were running with the `-next` option, this shouldn't be an issue.  Any ideas?

As a temporary workaround, I cleaned up the SpringBatch table in the database, but I don't want this to happen again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not aware of a -next option.

quickest way is to pass in the the current timestamp as a parameter to your job.  that way it will be unique and won't really interfere with your job.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm not certain how that works. Is that just something you add to the command line? You can learn about the `-next` option at [CommandLineJobRunner docs](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/launch/support/CommandLineJobRunner.html)

Comment: it is something you add in the command line. correct.  you pass it like another other JobParameter you normally would pass.  to use the -next command, you need to configure a JobParameterIncrementer.  The RunIdIncrementer is provided out of the box.  

<job id="job1" incrementer="jobParametersIncrementer">

 <bean id="jobParametersIncrementer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer" />

runIdincremeter allows you to set the name of the key as well. i read some where that there might be issues with perserving existing params....so be careful...else write ur own.

Comment: I created a new class for an incrementer which copied the RunIdIncrementer but also added in the current date/time.  This cleaned up the issue.

Answer (score 0):

With de -next option, you should set  a JobParametersIncrementer Implementation,

in this example i use -> new RunIdIncrementer to avoid the message : A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters

```
@Autowired
private JobBuilderFactory jobs;
...
@Bean(name=JOB_NAME)
public Job job() {        

    return jobs.get(JOB_NAME)
               .start(this.login())
               .next(this.launchDuke())
               .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
               .build();
}
```