# Spring Batch 'RunIdIncrementer' not generating next value

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have several Spring Batch (2.1.9.RELEASE) jobs running in production that use `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer`.

Sporadically, I get the following error:

```
org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException: A job instance already exists and is complete for parameters={run.id=23, tenant.code=XXX}.  If you want to run this job again, change the parameters.
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.createJobExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:122) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597) ~[na:1.6.0_39]
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:318) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110) ~[spring-tx-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean$1.invoke(AbstractJobRepositoryFactoryBean.java:168) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202) ~[spring-aop-3.1.1.RELEASE.jar:3.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy64.createJobExecution(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:111) ~[spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.start(CommandLineJobRunner.java:349) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner.main(CommandLineJobRunner.java:574) [spring-batch-core-2.1.9.RELEASE.jar:na]
    at (omitted for brevity)
```

A sampling from the various XML contexts:

```
<bean
    id="jobParametersIncrementer"
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer" />

<batch:job id="rootJob"
    abstract="true"
    restartable="true">
    <batch:validator>
        <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.DefaultJobParametersValidator">
            <property name="requiredKeys" value="tenant.code"/>
        </bean>
    </batch:validator>
</batch:job>

<batch:job id="rootJobWithIncrementer"
    abstract="true"
    parent="rootJob"
    incrementer="jobParametersIncrementer" />
```

I use `org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner` to execute the job:

```
java org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.CommandLineJobRunner /com/XXX/job123/job123-context.xml job123 tenant.code=XXX -next
```

All of the jobs (that use the incrementer) have `rootJobWithIncrementer` as parent.

I did quite a bit of research and found that some who got this error had success changing the isolation level of the transaction manager. I fiddled with several levels, finally arriving at `READ_COMMITED`.

```
<batch:job-repository
    id="jobRepository"
    data-source="oracle_hmp"
    transaction-manager="dataSourceTransactionManager"
    isolation-level-for-create="READ_COMMITTED"/>
```

Based on my understanding, this type of error should only happen if the *same* job is executed at the *same* time from multiple processes -- so that there might be contention for the incrementer. In this instance, that is **not** the case, yet we see the error.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this problem? Should I try a different isolation level? Something else?

Thanks!

*There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12976662/springbatch-commandlinejobrunner-next-using-old-run-id), but it is not as well documented (and also lacks and answer).*

Comment: Did you try default isolation level as mentioned [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring-batch/reference/html-single/index.html#txConfigForJobRepository)?  
Can you upgrade to 2.2.1.RELEASE (but changelog doesn't contains issues about incrementer)?

Comment: I tried several of the isolation levels, including the default - SERIALIZABLE. I will attempt the upgrade - our codebase is currently using Spring 3.1.X, but acording the the project POM, Spring Batch 2.2.1 requires Spring 3.2.X - I am somewhat concerned about an upgrade, but I will give it a shot. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This might be a long shot but it took me a long time to figure it out because the only symptom was sporadically getting the `JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException` as you describe so I figured I'd suggest it.

The database I was using was Oracle and the `BATCH_JOB_SEQ` and `BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_SEQ` I had created both had a `CACHE_SIZE` of 10.

This had the effect of sometimes causing the `JOB_INSTANCE_ID` and `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` to not be ordered correctly. Spring batch makes the assumption that the most recent `JOB_INSTANCE` is the one with `max(JOB_INSTANCE_ID)` (see `org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobInstanceDao.FIND_LAST_JOBS_BY_NAME`). Since my sequence was sometimes thrown off, this assumption did not always hold true.

I fixed it by setting the sequences to `NO_CACHE`.

An easy way to tell if this might be your problem is to check if your sequences are set to CACHE at all and/or to make sure that your `JOB_INSTANCE_ID` and `JOB_EXECUTION_ID` are always ascending with each new run.

Comment: Thanks @FGreg adding "INCREMENT BY 1" to the sequence was enough for me.